# How to Pass json Dtat in query param in php for pull service

Tags: php, rest, pull-request, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to get the data from pull service in PHP while i"m calling the end point in postman I'm getting the output  [image]
but while I'm trying to call using PHP I'm getting the 500
i have attaching the PHP code please guide me where I'm doing wrong

```
//API Url
$url = 'https://abc.xyz/vlet?Info=';
 

//The JSON data.
$jsonData = 
    array(
    'NAME' => 'anish',
    'Key' => 'vQOgCmDgxxdw',
    'authToken' => 'xswSgsG8Dtz05Rfhfzr83t25',
    'work_date' => '2020-07-07'
    
);



//print_r( $jsonData);  exit;
//Encode the array into JSON.
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
 
$full_url = $url.$jsonDataEncoded ; 
 //echo $full_url ; 
 $result1 = file_get_contents($full_url);
  print_r( $result1); 
 //Initiate cURL.
 $curl = curl_init();
 $ch = curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $full_url);
//$ch = curl_init($url);

//Tell cURL that we want to send a POST request.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 
//Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
 
//Set the content type to application/json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
 
//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: You can not put `?Info=` into the URL, and expect cURL to automatically translate that into a POST parameter. And your postman screenshot doesn’t look like you are actually sending `Content-Type: application/json` either. This looks like a normal form-urlencoded request, with one single parameter named `Info`, and the value of that being the JSON. So replicate _that_, properly.

Comment: yes I'm not sending the content type in body param, I have to send the request like that only and I'm getting the response could you please guide me how to send the request from php  for mention in screen shoot

Comment: I just tried to guide you with my previous comment. If that was not enough detail, then _explain_ what exactly you are still missing.